# How do I choose max bid price for AWS spot instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm confused about setting maximum price. For example, I'm approved to use g2.8xlarge spot instances in us-west region. In **Configure Instance Details** I am shown the following:

```
Availability Zone   Current price
us-west-2a          $1.261 USD
us-west-2b          $1.500 USD
us-west-2c          $26.00 USD
```

So I set max price to **$7** thinking that should easily get me an instance in us-west-2a or us-west-2b. However, on submitting the request I get

```
  Status: capacity-not-available: There is no Spot capacity 
available that matches your request.
```

Furthermore, the request description specifies:

```
Availability Zone: us-west-2c
```

...which suggests to me that my request is only being considered within the vastly more expensive of the three us-west sub-regions I was quoted prices from before. Thanks for any guidance you can offer me!

Comment: The answer below is good, but it does appear thst your request was only considered against one availability zone.  Unless the price is sitting at 10x the on-demand, there **is** capacity available, because that is what happens when capacity is not available -- the price sticks to the upper bound.  Select a specific AZ and try again.

Comment: Ah ok the trick was to begin the whole process as a spot request - this gives you ability to specify AZ's. Before I was starting from 'Launch Instance' and a few screens later clicking 'Request spot instances.'  For some reason this route does not let you specify AZ's. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at spot instances, look into several different instance types. Not all instance types are available at any given time. Availability varies by region. If the region does not matter, then you will have more choices.

Note: just because a spot price is specified, does not mean that there are any hosts with available instances. They could all be taken. Some companies will bid on thousands of instances which will keep utilization high. This typically happens with the very large instances, which by their nature are expensive and powerful and spot pricing makes these instances much cheaper. If you select middle of the road instances (in performance) you may have better luck.

For bidding price, look at the history of the instance by region. If the history price is close to On-Demand, move on. If the history is less the 50% (better 30%) of On-Demand and there are not too many price spikes per week or month going above 2x On-Demand, then look at bidding 2x On-Demand pricing. If you don't care when and how often your instances run, then bid 1.5x On-Demand.

Remember to make your instances stateless (e.g. store everything in a database, S3, etc.). Your instances may be terminated at any time. You can use ASG to keep a specific number of instances running.

[EDIT]
I just noticed that you are bidding on G2 instances. G2 instances are previous generation instances, which means that they are being phased out making spot bidding harder and harder. Bid instead on current generation instances such as the G3. Also unless you need Windows instances, bid on Linux instances.

Comment: Great insight. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. AWS certainly has a learning curve to it!

Comment: Yes, but so much fun while mastering cloud computing. Not too long ago we had to wait weeks while hardware arrived and then we would throw pizza parties while we put everything in racks. Now we can duplicate a small data center in AWS over coffee and desert.